# Changing woo commerce HTML that gets outputted with do_action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to build a webshop with woo commerce which seems like a very nice and easy to use system. But I'm really having some trouble with it. A lot of times there's a function like this in the code: `do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' )` which outputs some HTML that I really want to change. The documentation that is provided isn't making me any wiser. How can I change this HTML. I would really appreciate any help trying to understand how this works!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' )
```

this is action declared somewhere, this is done so that whenever you want to add anything for example say "hello there", you dont have to hardcode it .. you can simply do it this way ..

```
function add_something() {
  echo 'hello there';
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review','add_something');
```

**Refer here 
[Add Action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)**

This would add **"hello there"** in the rendered html page..exactly where you have `do_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review');` in the code . keep this snippet in your functions.php and play with it ;)

Comment: but how to replace the output (let's say replace the title within the output of the action)?

Comment: action hooks are not meant for data manipulation. filter hooks serve the purpose of data manipulation, you can check how filter works on wordpress codex. two important functions - `apply_filters` and `add_filter`

Comment: Downvoted. This does NOT show how you can change the HTML. I also wish to modify a bit of the content getting spitted out on: `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` -- not everything, but minor changes -- how do I do this?

Answer (score 20):

The answer to the question, **how do I modify the content ouputted in `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` ?**

### The answer:

The HTML is located in the template file here:

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php
```

You can easily modify this content in a plugin or theme. Read more about that here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. As good as @Wpdevstudio 's is, this answers the question *properly*